# MVC 4 losing session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, session

I have a base Controller which all the controllers extend, and at base controller I do some session handling. Such as storing user id etc.

Moreover, I have a `User` class which has other classes such as :

```
class User
{
   public int Id {set;get;}
   public virtual Location Location {set;get;}
}
```

When i populate this from Database (i m using code first EF), obviously Location wont load, Should i store this in the session the way it s?

Main question is I am storing `Id` in base controller and losing the session everytime i restart the application. why is that happening? i extended session timeout and didnt help.

What are the best practices for session handling? is there a wrapper i can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re: storing User in session:  You can, just make sure you don't ever access the 'Location' property without re-attaching it to a session.  If you don't need the data, an option is to just copy the data you *do* need into a simpler object that doesn't have 'Location' and store that in your Session.

Re: losing the session context, that's because the default is to store session data in memory, which is lost whenever the application restarts.  Take a look at using the [StateServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) mode for session if you want that state to persist across application restarts (though if you want to persist server restarts or work in a multi-server farm, you'll want to go the SQLServer route).

Answer (score -1):

That what you need - add this code to web.config/system.web:

```
<machineKey validationKey="C5034160419189092507195D247C6FCD9F54D7A967372A23078E09F6440087328A874AD69955F441B526A265CC3A17CDEAAE8AB21A16868F549C3077C39C8E9F" decryptionKey="078FAD13FAC4E41EB0762F0B34E3F4990A144897C3387A70A746187F3AECD8DE" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />   

    <sessionState timeout="300" mode="InProc"></sessionState>
```

this machinKey was generated from http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey